# who are those people with no profile page or rep?

Tags: support, reputation, users

Like the poster of [this question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/476/what-can-i-do-to-increase-battery-life-on-my-android-phone) th3dude and several of its answerers (tektor, etc)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those are questions that were migrated from the defunct Gadgets StackExchange.

See this blog post: [Pruning Season](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/pruning-season/)

*Update*: You'll also see this if the question gets migrated from another Stack Exchange site and the user does not have an account here.